# How do I shrink DevExpress row height in datagrid

Tags: css, devexpress

I am trying to make the rows much more compact in this DevExpress datagrid with no luck (React project).  I've reached out to DevExpress and they suggested editing in css but I cannot figure out how.  I'm assuming I need to remove the padding or margins.  Can someone please assist in editing the height of each row in my datagrid.  I basically want to remove all the extra spacing where I drew red lines.

[image: screenshot]

Also, when I google the issue it looks like DevExpress suggests this as well but it seems to do absolutely nothing when placed in my code.

```
.dx-datagrid .dx-row > td,
.dx-datagrid .dx-row > tr > td {
  padding: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an id to div containing the grid (eg. id="my-div") and at the end of 'theme.base.css' to add

```
#my-div .dx-data-row * {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Works for me.